Is there a PCMCIA Bluetooth card that would work in a Psion Series 7?
I am looking for a PCMCIA card that would add a Bluetooth serial port to my Psion Series 7.
The Psion Series 7 PCMCIA port has several limitations:

only has drivers for serial port
doesn't have drivers for networking
maximum current draw of 200mA

So I am looking for a 16-bit PCMCIA card that appears to the Psion as a single serial port (with RTS/CTS) and draws less than 200mA. It would need to controlled via AT commands or similar, though it might be controlled over the Bluetooth connection.
The Bluetooth profile will probably be SPP or DUN but the Psion won't know either way.
The only card I can find that appears to fit this description is the Ezurio Blu2i card, originally produced by TDK. However, this is hard to find.

If you think this is a shopping request please downvote or close, but I don't think such a card is currently in production.

Would a Bluetooth to RS-232 adapter work, like this?

@NoelWhitemore yes, I have one of those, but it involves more wire and needs to be externally powered. I would prefer a wireless solution.

Can you just use a PCMCIA card as the power source, then power the Bluetooth to RS-232 dongle off of it?

@NoelWhitemore I could probably hack the Psion to supply +V over the RS-232 RI line, which would power my serial / Bluetooth adapter. I just though PCMCIA would be neater.

What about if you had a PCMCIA-to-RS-232 card, and then plugged your Bluetooth-to-RS-232 adaptor into that? Possibly a bit bulky, but could you power the adaptor that way?

Not an out-of-the-box solution, but yyzkevin has a Raspberry Pico W PCMCIA card (as in: the Rasppi is on the card).
As it's a Raspberry, emulating a serial port via software shouldn't be a problem, as well as the glue to get to Bluetooth. Newer Raspberry Pico W's also have do Bluetooth.
I have no idea though if the 200mA are sufficient. My guess would be that most likely not, but since you'd have to make a custom card anyway, maybe you can find some other way to supply additional current.
The big downside is that you have to build the hardware, and program the software yourself in one way or other.

There is a similar idea at https://www.electricstuff.co.uk/diyserial.html which would taking the modem driver chip out of a PCMCIA modem and replacing with a Bluetooth SPP module, such as HC-05.
